# Как правильно - филиал в г. Смоленск или филиал в г. Смоленске?

Tags: падежи

Подскажите, почему в названии организации " Филиал ПАО "МТС" в г. Смоленск", слово "Смоленск" употреблено в именительном падеже, а в названии Администрация Промышленного района в г. Смоленске, слово "Смоленск" употреблено в предложном падеже?

Answer (score 3):

Корректно: в городе Смоленске. Название склоняется.

Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями город, село, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование.

Правильно: в городе Москве, в городе Санкт-Петербурге, из города Киева; в деревню Ивановку, из деревни Ольховки, в селе Шушенском, под хутором Михайловским; у реки Волги, долина ручья Сухого.

**В этой связи следует также упомянуть и родовое слово "город".**

В «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К. Чельцовой указано, что «сокращение г. (город), как и полное слово, рекомендуется употреблять ограниченно, главным образом перед названиями городов, образованными от фамилий (г. Киров)».

Таким образом, общеупотребительно: в Москве. Варианты в г. Москве, в городе Москве  следует характеризовать как специфически-канцелярские (т. е. употребительные преимущественно в официально-деловой речи). Варианты в г. Москва, в городе Москва не соответствуют литературной норме.

[Источник: Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

Comment: Добавлю к ответу. Правильно так: _Администрация Промышленного района г. Смоленска_ (без предлога **в**, то есть в родительном падеже). Причём в 
[полном юридическом наименовании](https://www.list-org.com/company/866969) слово **города** написано полностью.